# Exporting php data in a loop to CSV file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, export-to-csv

I have written a code which uses the API of fantasypremierleague.com to extract data. The data is being extracted for 38 gameweeks using a for loop. I print the data using echo to verify that it is correct.
I am having a problem converting the data into CSV files using a script since its in a loop.
After printing information each gameweek i have added a button (in total 38 buttons) which should convert the information of each gameweek to a CSV file.

Currently, all the buttons are printing the information of gameweek 1 even though the script is part of the loop.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
for ($i=1; $i <39 ; $i++) { 


$json=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/entry/1224012/event/".$i."/picks");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$json1=file_get_contents("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/elements/");
$data1 = json_decode($json1, true);

?>

<table id ="gameweek_history">
<tr>
 <th>Average Gameweek Score</th>
 <th>Highest Score</th>
 <th>Highest Scorer ID</th>
</tr>
</br>
</br>

<td><?PHP echo $data['event']['average_entry_score']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['event']['highest_score']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['event']['highest_scoring_entry']; ?></td>

</table>


<table id ="gameweek_info">
<tr>
 <th>Gameweek</th>
 <th>Active Chip</th>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Points</th>
 <th>Total Points</th>
 <th>Rank</th>
 <th>Overall Rank</th>
 <th>Gameweek Transfers</th>
 <th>Gameweek Transfer Cost</th>
 <th>Points on Bench</th>
 <th>Bank</th>
 </tr>
 </br>
 </br>

<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['event']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['active_chip']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['id']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['points']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['total_points']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['rank']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['overall_rank']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['event_transfers']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['event_transfers_cost']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['points_on_bench']; ?></td>
<td><?PHP echo $data['entry_history']['bank']; ?></td>

</table>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<script>function doCSV() {
 var table1 = document.getElementById("gameweek_history").innerHTML;
 var data1 = table1.replace(/<thead>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/thead>/g, '')
 .replace(/<tbody>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/tbody>/g, '')
 .replace(/<tr>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/tr>/g, '\r\n')
 .replace(/<th>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/th>/g, ',')
 .replace(/<td>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/td>/g, ',')
 .replace(/\t/g, '')
 .replace(/\n/g, '');
 var table2 = document.getElementById("gameweek_info").innerHTML;
 var data2 = table2.replace(/<thead>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/thead>/g, '')
 .replace(/<tbody>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/tbody>/g, '')
 .replace(/<tr>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/tr>/g, '\r\n')
 .replace(/<th>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/th>/g, ',')
 .replace(/<td>/g, '')
 .replace(/<\/td>/g, ',')
 .replace(/\t/g, '')
 .replace(/\n/g, '');
 var data= data1.concat(data2);
 var mylink = document.createElement('a');
 mylink.download = "Gameweek.csv";
 mylink.href = "data:application/csv," + escape(data);
 mylink.click();
}</script>

<button onclick="doCSV()">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>

<?PHP
}
?>
```

I expect each button to convert the information of the particular gameweek which the loop is currently on (for e.g. i i=1 then gameweek 1 team should be exported, if i=2 then gameweek2 team should be exported)

Comment: All of your tables are being created with the same id, so the javascript can't tell them apart.

Comment: Yeah I had an idea it was that but I am not sure how to fix it. Could you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add unique ids to every table like:

```
<table id ="gameweek_history<? echo $i; ?>">
```

Then you'll need to have your javascript refer to the id. Your existing code creates a new script for every table, so to keep doing that, each function will need a unique name that has refers to that table.

```
<script>function doCSV<? echo $i; ?>() {
var table1 = document.getElementById("gameweek_history<? echo $i; ?>").innerHTML;
```

It would probably be better to just have one function declared outside the loop with a variable passed into it.

```
<script>function doCSV(table_number) {
var table1 = document.getElementById("gameweek_history" + table_number).innerHTML;
```

Then add the table number to each event handler.

```
<button onclick="doCSV(<? echo $i; ?>)">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button>
```

Comment: i tried the changes you suggested but the download buttons are no longer working. This is what i have so far inside the loop:
<table id ="gameweek_history<? echo $i; ?>">
<button onclick="doCSV(<? echo $i; ?>)">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button> and i have the following outside the loop

<script>function doCSV(table_number) {
var table1 = document.getElementById("gameweek_history" + table_number).innerHTML;